# Using laptop's light sensor in Linux

Tags: python, ruby, linux, bash, shell

My laptop is a VAIO VPCF1 and has a light sensor to lighten the keyboard when it's dark. I want to use this sensor as a security tool. As a password. For example, I execute an script and put my finger three times on the  sensor so some locked thing can unlock. Is there any way to use my laptop's sensor to get the amount of light?

Python code, Ruby code, a program, it doesn't matter. I just want to use it in an Arch Linux.

Comment: Did you do some research before asking?  What did you find?

Comment: Have you checked /sys/devices/platform/sony-laptop directory? You might need to compile the sony-laptop module.

Comment: FakeRainBrigand: Yeah, I searched. But I couldn't find anything useful. Actually, I pretty much found nothing

Comment: Michal Trybus: I found two files: kbd_backlight and kbd_backlight_timeout. I probably won't need the second one, but in the first one, the only thing written is a 1. How can I use it?

Comment: I found this part of X called xbacklight. But when I run it, it says "No outputs have backlight property"